# Uploading Historical Work Orders via FM or BAPI

Tags: abap

I am currently working on a project that requires me to upload historical work orders, notification, long texts, etc. After completing my initial development using BAPI "BAPI_ALM_ORDER_MAINTAIN", I noticed that this function module is creating regular work orders, not historical work orders.

Is there a way to designate in this BAPI that I would like **historical** orders to be created instead, or should I look at another function module?

EDIT: I have posted the answer below.

Comment: Have you caught a glimpse of the transaction `LSMW`?

Comment: I've seen it recommended in similar business cases, but I was hoping that I wouldn't have to go that route. From my research of LSMW, it seems that using it to migrate SAP to SAP (instead of non-SAP to SAP) could create various issues, or require extra work. It is certainly a possible solution still, but I was hoping for something that could be done via code since I am writing a ETL process for this migration.

Comment: Sure LSMW could be used for migrating non-SAP to SAP.

Comment: So you are taking your orders from another SAP system? In what form?

Comment: It looks like LSMW is the only option, or writing you custom FM which will utilize BDC.

Comment: I know this is late, but I just remembered to update this. We ended up using a custom ABAP report paired with the SARA tool provided by SAP to update and archive orders.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I just remembered to update this. We ended up using a custom ABAP report paired with the SARA tool provided by SAP to update and archive orders

Comment: maybe you will give couple of lines of code you used for updating